# Is it programmatically possible to update a windows store apps from within the app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, updates, auto-update, programmatically-created

Is there an API that allows to me to programmatically pull the latest update from the store and refresh the current version that the user is using?  If not, is it possible for the current app to programmatically know that there is a new version available?

Any samples/examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: in 8.1, apps auto-update

Comment: But this is shown on the Windows store, correct?.  If the user is never looking for an update and never goes to the store, she will never be aware that there is an update available.  I would like to be able to push an update (at least send a message) to the user.

Comment: No, in 8.1 it actually auto updates with no action from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using WNS and Azure Notification Hub to send a push notification to the app when it is launched. The notification is in the form of a toast message that essentially states that a new release is available.  But if you updated/downloaded the app after xx/xx/xxxx, no updates are necessary.

I know it is a little cludgy but at least the users now know that the version of the app that they are using may be dated.  I control the notification through Azure Mobile Service (which is free for up to 10 apps) and can fully modify the actual script.

Answer (score 2):

You can't programmatically install any Store software. But you can programmatically open the Store to let it do the user manually.

That said, there's no official Store API which you could ask about app versions (you might be able to parse the Store's HTML pages, but I recommend against this approach).

What you can do: Put a small XML file on your website which contains the latest app version number. Your app then can read this file and compare this desired version against the running app's version. If the app is outdated, the app can show a message box to the user.